# Python Main Process/Thread Not Terminating in MultiProcessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, freeze

I spawn a number of processes and then have them set an event when a condition is found.  For some reason, after all the spawned processes have been terminated (I can see them be discarded in OS process table), the python program doesn't exit.  It just stays alive at 0 utilization.

```
import hashlib
import requests

import sys
import json

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event


### Threading Setup ###
q = Queue()
processes = []
num_workers = 8


### Local Results Store ###
class NodeInfo():
    def __init__(self, miner_id=None, server_url=None):
        self.miner_id = miner_id
        self.server_url = server_url

    @property
    def verification_url(self):
        if self.server_url is not None:
            return self.server_url + '/verify'    

class Results():
    def __init__(self, results=[]):
        self.proof = Queue()

    def add_result(self, result):
        if result:
            self.proof.put(result)

    @property
    def success(self):
        return not self.proof.empty()

node_info = NodeInfo()
results = Results()


def block_hash(block: dict):
    """
    Creates a SHA-256 hash of a Block
    :param block": <dict> Block
    "return": <str>
    """

    # Use json.dumps to convert json into a string
    # Use hashlib.sha256 to create a hash
    # It requires a `bytes-like` object, which is what
    # .encode() does.
    # It converts the Python string into a byte string.
    # We must make sure that the Dictionary is Ordered,
    # or we'll have inconsistent hashes

    new_hash = hashlib.sha256(
            json.dumps(block, sort_keys=True).encode()).hexdigest()
    # print(len(new_hash), new_hash)
    return new_hash


def validate_proof(block, proof, difficulty):
    """
    Validates the Proof:  Does hash(block_string, proof) contain 3
    leading zeroes?  Return true if the proof is valid
    :param block_string: <string> The stringified block to use to
    check in combination with `proof`
    :param proof: <int?> The value that when combined with the
    stringified previous block results in a hash that has the
    correct number of leading zeroes.
    :return: True if the resulting hash is a valid proof, False otherwise
"""

block_string = json.dumps(block, sort_keys=True)

guess_hash = str(block_hash(
    f'{block_string}{proof}'
))
return '0'*difficulty == guess_hash[0:difficulty]



def proof_of_work(block, search_space:list, difficulty: int):
    """
    Modified Proof of Work Algorithm
    Stringify the block and look for a proof.
    Loop through defined search_space of possibilities, checking each one against `valid_proof` in an effort to find a number that is a valid proof
    :return: A valid proof for the provided block
    """

    # Validate search_space
    assert len(search_space) == 2, 'Search space only accepts [start_int, end_int]'
    assert type(search_space[0]) == int, 'Must provide integer start' 
    assert type(search_space[1]) == int, 'Must provide integer end'

    valid_proof = False
    guess = search_space[0]

    while guess < search_space[1]:
        valid_proof = validate_proof(
            block=block, 
            proof=guess, 
            difficulty=difficulty
            )
        if valid_proof:
            return guess
        guess += 1

    return None


def request_block(url):
    """ Request last block from server with given URL """
    r = requests.get(url = url)
    try:
        data = r.json()
    except:
        raise

    return(data)


def check_proof():
    if results.success:
        print('Validating \n')
        check = requests.post(url=node_info.verification_url, json = {
            'miner_id': node_info.miner_id,
            'proof': results.proof.get(),
        })
        return check


def mine(job):
    print(f"Starting to mine{job['search_space']}")
    proof = proof_of_work(
        block=job['block'],
        search_space=job['search_space'],
        difficulty=job['difficulty']
    )
    if proof is not None:
        results.add_result(proof)
        return True
    return False


def miner(pquit, foundit):
    while not pquit.is_set():
        if q.empty():
            break
        job = q.get()
        if job is None:
            break
        if mine(job):
            print('Found proof!')
            check = check_proof()
            print(check.json())
            foundit.set()
            break


def create_jobs(block_info, max_search = 2**24, num_jobs=0):
    segment = max_search/num_workers
    jobs = []

    # Dynamically size number of jobs based on max_search
    if num_jobs == 0:
        num_jobs = int(max_search/10000)

    for i in range(num_jobs):
        search_space = [
            int(i*segment), int((i+1)*segment)
        ]
        job = {
            'block': block_info['last_block'],
            'search_space': search_space,
            'difficulty': block_info['difficulty'],
        }
        jobs.append(job)

    return jobs



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # What is the server address? IE `python3 miner.py https://server.com/api/`
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        node_info.server_url = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        node_info.server_url = "http://localhost:5000"

    # Load ID
    #f = open("my_id.txt", "r")
    node_info.miner_id = 'test_id'  #f.read()
    print("ID is", node_info.miner_id)
    #f.close()

    # Get last block
    block_info = request_block(url=node_info.server_url + '/last_block')

    # # Search for proof (single-threaded)
    # proof = proof_of_work(block=block_info['last_block'], search_space=[0, 2**256], difficulty=block_info['difficulty'])
    # print('Proof:', proof)

    # Search for proof (multi-threaded)
    jobs = create_jobs(block_info=block_info)
    print(jobs[0], jobs[-1])

    # Load queue
    for job in jobs:
        q.put(job)

    # Start multiple processes
    pquit = Event()
    foundit = Event()
    for i in range(num_workers):
        p = Process(target=miner, args=(pquit, foundit))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    foundit.wait()
    pquit.set()

    for p in processes:
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
    print('All Done')
```

The .py file can be found here: https://github.com/newnativeabq/Blockchain/blob/assignment/client_mining_p/miner.py

I went with processes because of the GIL locking the script execution to a single file. I think I had the same problem in the threading library too.

OS: Fedora 31
python version: 3.7.4

Comment: Can you please share the hole code, or at least all mentioned functions, so that I can replicated the error.

Comment: Updated with full code